# How to compile source file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I really love `Sublime Text 2` and I want to use it for Software programming.

The problem is that our source files are stored on a Linux server and we all work using `PuTTy` to connect and `Vim` to edit the code. We can compile the source by executing a command in `PuTTy`.

I want to use `Sublime Text 2` for coding (the folders in Linux are mounted on our Windows system so the files can be opened in Windows). But whenever I want to compile, I have to open `PuTTy` and compile manually which asks a lot of time. Can I automate this somehow? Like if I push a button (F8 for example) then `PuTTy` opens, connects to the Linux server with `SSH` goes to the correct folder and compiles the source file. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Build Systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) can be used to launch a process like this.

I'm not sure if you can automate anything using putty. But the fork named ExtraPutty allows this: it is [scriptable using Lua](http://www.extraputty.com/features/logon_script.html), an you can [launch a script from command line](http://www.extraputty.com/htmldoc/AppendixA.html).

If you arefamiliar with Javascript, another alternative would be to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) + a module like [SSH2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ssh2) to automate you compilation process, then launch it from a Sublime build system. The [ssh](https://github.com/andrewrjones/grunt-ssh) module does not allow interactive commands to be scripted, so I recommend you to use SSH2.

There are many other options; pick the one with which you're the more confortable, then use Sublime Build system to launch it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm getting in the right direction. Grunt seems very difficult because I never heard of it. But I think I can give Lua scripting a try. But I have the following: 
When I try the logon_script (http://www.extraputty.com/features/logon_script.html). Then I get `input:2: attempt to call global 'lua_send_login_password' (a nil value)`. You can try to run the script here too: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Comment: Can you give me some other options other then lua scripting an grunt that I can follow? Can I for example create a C# application and call the exe?

Comment: Look at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-task-automation/

Comment: Whats important is that I always need my full path of the file I'm working on, so I think I need to stick to the Sublime Text build systems. I'll try further. I'll keep this topic updated

Comment: Using C# is an option indeed. Like (almost) any other programming language, as long as it allow you to automate your compilation process.